# How to insert multiple data of the same name from single form with multiple row of multiple form

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have this code working fine with single input data

index.php

```
 <form method="post" id="insert_form">
        <div class="table-repsonsive">
          <span id="error"></span>
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Customer Name <td><select name="item_name[]" class="form-control item_name"><option value="">Select Name</option><?php echo fill_select_boxing($connect, "10"); ?></select></td></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Sub Category</th>
                <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
          <div align="center">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      
      var count = 0;

      $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
        count++;
        var html = '';
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td><select name="item_category[]" class="form-control item_category" data-sub_category_id="'+count+'"><option value="">Select Category</option><?php echo fill_select_box($connect, "0"); ?></select></td>';
        html += '<td><select name="item_sub_category[]" class="form-control item_sub_category" id="item_sub_category'+count+'"><option value="">Select Sub Category</option></select></td>';
        html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td>';
        $('tbody').append(html);
      });
    });
</script>
```

insert.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["item_category"]))
{
 include('database_connection.php');

 for($count = 0; $count < count($_POST["item_category"]); $count++)
 {
  $data = array(
   ':item_name'   => $_POST["item_name"][$count],
   ':item_category_id'  => $_POST["item_category"][$count],
   ':item_sub_category_id' => $_POST["item_sub_category"][$count]
  );

  $query = "
   INSERT INTO mapping   
       (item_name, item_category_id, item_sub_category_id) 
       VALUES (:item_name, :item_category_id, :item_sub_category_id)
  ";

  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

  $statement->execute($data,);
 }

 echo 'ok';
}

?>
```

when i try to add more than one category input in my web, the code just insert the first row to mysql

data that i have is :

- customer : CustA
- item 1 : chair
- item 2 : table

i want to insert those data like this :

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| custA | chair |
| custA | table |

Answer (score 1):

You can bind your variables in the for loop, then execute.
There are also options to bindParam you can add to account for different data types.
Look in the PHP documentation online for bindParam options.

```
if(isset($_POST["item_category"]))
{
 include('database_connection.php');

 $query = "
   INSERT INTO mapping   
       (item_name, item_category_id, item_sub_category_id) 
       VALUES (:item_name, :item_category_id, :item_sub_category_id)
  ";

  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

 for($count = 0; $count < count($_POST["item_category"]); $count++)
 {
 $statement->bindParam(':item_name', $_POST["item_name"][$count]);
 $statement->bindParam(':item_category_id', $_POST["item_category"][$count]);
 $statement->bindParam(':item_sub_category_id', $_POST["item_sub_category"][$count]);
 $statement->execute();
  } // end for
  


 echo 'ok';
} // end if
```

Comment: its still the same, only insert the first data

Comment: Moved the execute inside the for loop